# passing graphics object to action method

Tags: object, graphics, 3d, paint, actionmethod

I need to pass the grapics object 'g' to the action method from the paint method. 
Something like this:

```
 public boolean action(Event event, Object obj)
 {   

   Graphics g=getGraphics();
   repaint();

   if (event.target == choice) 
   String selection = choice.getSelectedItem();
   if (selection.equals("do something"))
   {
       doSomething(g);
       repaint();
   }
   else if (selection.equals("do something else"))
   {
       Somethingelse(g);
       repaint();
   }

   return(true);
}

      else
          return(false);
   }
```

I tried to declare g as a global graphics variable but it doesnt work. Is there another way to do this. Any help is appreciated .. Thanks..

Comment: What language is this? Is this Java?

Comment: The object and 3d tags don't make much sense if this is really java. Smells a lot like Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is java and you are overriding a Swing component (so getGraphics() is actually available).

Try `Graphics g = this.createGraphics()`, that might help. Also, be sure to call the `repaint()` methods from the Event Dispatch Thread. If this action is linked to the UI, that is generally the case. To be sure, wrap the repaints in a Runnable and send it to the end of the EDT:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        repaint();
    }
}
```